# Find distance between point layer and lines layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-grass-plugin

All the answers were for one point and one line, But I'm talking about one point and multiple lines, and for older versions of QGIS.

I have two shapefiles including one point layer and multiple lines layer about 5000 lines shapefile.

Does anybody know a solution to this?

I'm not familiar with PyQGIS and Python and I have "QGIS 3.0.1 Girona".

Comment: have a look at hub and spokes tool in processing toolbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your target point has a unique `id` field, and the `id` of the said point is `1` (for example), it can be referenced by `get_feature('point', 'id', '1')` from the other layer.

So, open the attribute table of your line layer, start the Field Calculator, and create a new numeric field by:

```
distance($geometry, geometry(get_feature('point', 'id', '1')))
```

Then it will return distance from the point (`id`=`1`) to each line.

Comment: I have done what you said exactly. A new field that I named it dist, has been added but no distance were calculated.
Though I pushed *update all* botton but an error occured:

"An error occured while evaluating the calculation string : No root node! Parsing faild?

Comment: @NimaDolatabadi Can you see `Field calculator` button? Pushing *update all* button doesn't sound like you are doing it as I have described...

Comment: I have done exactly what you said. I did use the update all on my own to check if it would make amy difference at all. Without it. Just new field is made but no distances are calculated

Comment: @NimaDolatabadi Ccould you add the layer name of point layer, id field name and the id you used for the calculation, along with the expression you gave?

Comment: I went through a mistake. All you said was true. Distances are calculated properly. Best Regards.

Comment: It seems there is another problem here. My calculated distances are only three numbers: "1", "2", "0". And there is another question here. What is the unit of this numbers? Meter or kilometer? I'm having CRS, WGS 84

Comment: @NimaDolatabadi Yes, it will be in degrees. You would need to reproject both layers to CRS which use X-Y (meters). Do you have such CRS you would like to use?

Comment: if it's in degrees I can manage the calculation to kilometers. But why distance fucntion doesn't calculate exact value of distance? Every degree is about 111 kilometer. It would be that all my distances are 111, 222 and 0. Is this really true?

Comment: @NimaDolatabadi I think you chose `Whole number (integer)` for the `dist` field type in the Field Calculator. You would need it be `Decimal number`.

Comment: your solution worked perfectly. I just got the idea. Thank you for your detailed information

Comment: @NimaDolatabadi Thanks letting me know, I am glad it worked :D